# Is Peano Arithmetic the most-commonly used arithmetic system

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I am learning mathematical logic. I want to ask whether the current arithmetic system that we are talking about is Peano Arithmetic. For instance, when we say we want to prove some conjectures, such as Goldbach's conjecture, are we saying that we want to prove them in Peano Arithmetic? Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Yes, for sure [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) are the "most common" way to formalize arithmetical theory.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, we just focus on proving conjectures on Peano Arithmetic. May I know whether in any cases, we would create a new arithmetic system.

Comment: As per answer below, it is not necessary to work in a "formalized" way. We prove facts about numbers using already proven theorems about number. The relevant result is that all known arithmetical "usual" facts can be proved starting from Peano axioms. Things can be different for "advanced topics" in number theory (see e.g. [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)).

Comment: Thank you so much. So, by godel's incompleteness, we could construct a Godel's sentence in Peano Arithmetic; and we knew that the godel's sentence is a $\pi 1$ sentence, and Goldbach's conjecture is also a $\pi$ 1 sentence. This just implies that Goldbach's conjecture could be unable to be proven  in Peano Arithmetic. Not saying that it could be unable to be proven in other arithmetic systems, besides that one taking the conjecture as axiom. Sorry, I don't know whether I have made my point clear..

Comment: See the post [Could Goldbach's conjecture be proven unprovable using Gödel's first incompleteness theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417448/could-goldbachs-conjecture-be-proven-unprovable-using-g%C3%B6dels-first-incompleten)

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhh, I have just seen the post. So, we are still focusing on Peano Arithmetic to prove the Goldbach's conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I think that when people do arithmetic on a higher level (such as number theory) they are, most of the time, not all too conscious about exactly what arithmetic they use. Just as someone doing topology isn't too concerned with the intricacies of ZFC set theory, or whether they are using some other set theory.

It's about focus. You just can't spend too much energy thinking about the details of the construction of a building's foundation when you decorate a 4th floor apartment. It just isn't worth it in general.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am thinking like, if we want to prove a conjecture, we can just make that conjecture an axiom to a new arithmetic system....